# How can we organize different types of activities in a day according to Islam?

Tags: practical-islam

As there are five wakt salat in a day, and these divide a day in-consecutively. Like,

> Fajr-Zuhr: around 7-8 hours
>
> Zuhr-Asr : around around 3-4 hours
>
> Asr-Magrib: around 2 hours &
>
> Magrinb-Esha: around 1-1.5 hours

So, Its clear that time span is being shorter consecutively in a day. I'm very curious to know if there is anything said about a organized day to get a most effective day. As, we all do know that it is said to go for finding works after Farj prayer, going to sleep after Esha prayer & I saw somewhere, something like this:

> Fajr prayer: For illuminating face
>
> Zuhr prayer: For blessed wealth
>
> Asr prayer: for a healthy body
>
> Magrib prayer: For blessed children &
>
> Esha prayer: For a restful sleep

So, are the intervals between these prayers and different types of blessing of these are meant to organize these times in any way?

Comment: please refine ur question, be clear plz....

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. For one, this is highly dependent on physical geography.

Comment: I found it difficult to explain more clearly. Anyway thanks for your concern.. Jazakallah Khair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description in your question is not clear so I will go with the Title "How can we organize different types of activities in a day according to Islam?" and somewhat tailor it to include the prayers.

Islam allows all activities that are not termed as haram, gambling for example. So the best way to organize your halal activities is to make provision for prayers.

For example, you wake up during Fajr prayer, offer your prayer, go for exercise or wakeup, Fajr, go to work.

In the afternoon make a habit of having lunch after Zohor prayer.

In the evening make a habit of starting your evening activity just after offering Asr prayer

Have dinner after Magrib, do a bit of reading or whatever you want to do after Asha and go to bed.

I am leaving out the activities that you need to place between prayers since it depends on what you do and the activities that you need to perform during the day. However, linking activities to after prayer can be a cool way.

**AND ALLAH KNOWS BEST.**

Comment: This is good indeed, you got my question. I also think that our daily activities can be divided along with the prayers. Since prayers divided a day into different times and these different times are good for different activities. As the description of my question (which info I found in the web), I was thinking if there are any valid research about the prayer timing, or if its more than just the 5 wakt prayer which can makes our life well organized.. JazakAllah khayer for your answer